# Override plugin options default values

Tags: jquery, variables, default

```
$.fn.formreg=function(options){
 options = $.extend({}, $.fn.formreg.defaults, options);
 return this.each(function() {
 var $this =  $(this) ;  
   });         
  };


$.fn.formreg.defaults={
stepWidths:0,
 sliding_time:200,
 step_opacity:0.8,
 'step_id':'steps',
 nav_id:'navigation'
}
```

this is how I use the plugin and passing options values.

```
$('#formElem').formreg({
     sliding_time:900,  //sliding time 
     step_opacity:0.2, // FieldSet alpha effect when sliding  , 1 means 100%
     step_id:'steps2', // Id of the sliding main container .. 
     nav_id:'navigation2', // Id of navigation bottom buttons..
    });
```

Problem is that whatever the sent vaule , values never change

Comment: `'step_id'` is that a mistake? a typo? (the `' '` around `step_id`) Where is the rest of your plugin?

Comment: when I use  step_id:'steps'  nothing changed ,

Comment: comma at end of options list?

Comment: Removing comma also doesn't affect the results :(

Comment: @wizard999 could you set up an example on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), makes it easier to see the problem :)

Comment: now I want to replace default values with custom values